# Los divs no cambian de tamaño en la misma linea

Tags: css

Tengo un problema. Tengo estos divs con imágenes de fondo y les estoy ampliando el ancho cuando hago hover, pero las imágenes no se mantienen en línea y las envía hacia abajo, y además como que se traban al ampliarlas. ¿Cómo hago para que las imágenes cambien su ancho en la línea en la que están y que no envíe las otras imágenes hacia abajo y no se traben?

También como algo extra puse un texto y lo estoy tratando de poner en medio horizontal y vertical y que el texto aparezca de igual manera cuando se hace hover en el div y se amplia de tamaño.

```css
.imgs-cont{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    text-align: center;
}
.img-cont{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19%;
    height: 500px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
}
.img-cont:hover{
    width: 50%;
}
#img1{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/27/21/43/startup-3267505_960_720.jpg');
}
#img2{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/11/19/office-1209640_960_720.jpg');
}
#img3{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/19/17/53/writing-1149962_960_720.jpg');
}
#img4{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/27/06/30/skyscraper-3184798_960_720.jpg');
}
#img5{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/09/19/56/office-932926_960_720.jpg');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imgs-cont">
        <div class="img-cont" id="img1">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-cont" id="img2">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-cont" id="img3">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-cont" id="img4">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-cont" id="img5">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.imgs-cont{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
.img-cont{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 19%;
    height: 500px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
}
.img-cont:hover{
    width: 50%;
}
#img1{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/27/21/43/startup-3267505_960_720.jpg');
}
#img2{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/11/19/office-1209640_960_720.jpg');
}
#img3{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/19/17/53/writing-1149962_960_720.jpg');
}
#img4{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/27/06/30/skyscraper-3184798_960_720.jpg');
}
#img5{
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/09/19/56/office-932926_960_720.jpg');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imgs-cont">
        <div class="img-cont" id="img1">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-cont" id="img2">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-cont" id="img3">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-cont" id="img4">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-cont" id="img5">
            <p>Texto</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hola, yo lo hice con **display flex**. Así utilizo la propiedad **justify-content** y **align-items** que me sirve para alinear o redistribuir el contenido.

Comment: Si, era por eso. Y con lo del texto, como le puedo hacer para que cuando haga hover en el div, además de que el div se haga más ancho, que el texto aparezca?

Answer (score 0):

me atreví a resolver lo que comentabas en la otra respuesta.

Para hacer que el texto aparezca, debes controlar el `display` del parrafo.
Primero no se verá, por lo que inicializamos con `display: none;`

Posteriormente, este aparecerá, pero si no quieres que aparezca de golpe, le agregamos un `fade-in` que queda perfecto para el tema.

Acá ya puedes controlar el resto, color, duración de la animación, etc.

```css
.imgs-cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.img-cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 19%;
  height: 500px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

.img-cont:hover {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.img-cont .txt {
  display: none;
  animation: fadeIn 0.8s;

}

.img-cont:hover .txt {
  display: flex;
  animation: fadeIn 0.8s;
}


@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#img1 {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/27/21/43/startup-3267505_960_720.jpg');
}

#img2 {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/11/19/office-1209640_960_720.jpg');
}

#img3 {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/01/19/17/53/writing-1149962_960_720.jpg');
}

#img4 {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/27/06/30/skyscraper-3184798_960_720.jpg');
}

#img5 {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/09/19/56/office-932926_960_720.jpg');
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="imgs-cont">
      <div class="img-cont" id="img1">
        <p class="txt">Texto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-cont" id="img2">
        <p class="txt">Texto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-cont" id="img3">
        <p class="txt">Texto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-cont" id="img4">
        <p class="txt">Texto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-cont" id="img5">
        <p class="txt">Texto</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```